# Using Scala IDE and Apache Spark on Windows

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to start working on a project that uses Spark with Scala on Windows 7.
I downloaded the Apache Spark pre-build for hadoop 2.4 ([download page](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)) and I can run it from command prompt (cmd). I can run all of the codes on the quick start of spark page before self-contains application section.

Then I downloaded Scala IDE 4.0.0 from its download page (Sorry it's not possible to post more than 2 links).

Now I created a new scala project and also import the spark assembly jar file into the project. When I want to run the example in the self-contains application section in quick start of spark page but I got the following errors:

```
15/03/26 11:59:55 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077/user/Master...

15/03/26 11:59:58 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077

15/03/26 11:59:58 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: myhost

15/03/26 12:00:15 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077/user/Master...

15/03/26 12:00:17 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077

15/03/26 12:00:17 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: myhost

15/03/26 12:00:35 INFO AppClient$ClientActor: Connecting to master akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077/user/Master...

15/03/26 12:00:37 WARN AppClient$ClientActor: Could not connect to akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077: akka.remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077

15/03/26 12:00:37 WARN Remoting: Tried to associate with unreachable remote address [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@myhost:7077]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: myhost

15/03/26 12:00:55 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.

15/03/26 12:00:55 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Exiting due to error from cluster scheduler: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.

15/03/26 12:00:55 WARN SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application ID is not initialized yet.
```

The only line of code that I add to the example, is .setMaster("spark://myhost:7077") for SparkConf definition. I think I need to configure the Scala IDE to use the pre-build spark on my computer but actually I don't know how and I couldn't find anything by googling.

Could you help me to get Scala IDE works with the spark on windows 7?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are in for a *huge* uphill battle trying to develop Scala and Spark apps on windoze.  Trust me.  I recommend a Mac dev env, and learn to use the terminal as it will help when you need Linux.  It is well worth the learning curve.. if you are serious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

I should correct the master definition in my code as follow:

replace:

```
.setMaster("spark://myhost:7077")
```

with:

```
.setMaster("local[*]")
```

Hope that it helps you as well.

Comment: By doing this you are running in a local context.  Meaning that you are not running on a cluster of any sort.

Comment: I wanted to run on a local mode.

Comment: Just an FYI.  What you are replacing is correct, but only for cluster/client mode.